# Jquery tabs, how to indicate validation errors in other tabs when saving from another tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using jquery tabs to allow my user to enter information. So right now I have also 5 tabs and each tabs have a couple of fields in them. Many fields have client side jquery validation used for them. And across each tab I have used a common save button.

So say the user is on TAB 2 and he tries to save but the validation on TAB 1 fails, so in such cases I want to tell the user that TAB 1 has some validation error which he needs to correct and then only can he save.

So for this I was planning to add a error icon next to the tab name whenever that tab has any validation errors.

How do I add an icon to the tab header ?

Is there any other better idea which I could use for my problem. Please advice.

Comment: If you're using twitter bootstrap it's easy to put an icon. Please check my fiddle. If we are having the same thought http://jsfiddle.net/rcgAX/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I used, with a little help from the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rcgAX/) which [Drixson Oseña](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2526499/drixson-osena) shared in his comment. Hope this helps others too :)

Update fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/yrshaikh/rcgAX/2/

**Html**

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor<span id="tab1" class="boing">!</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Tab1</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Tab2</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Tab3</p>
  </div>
</div>

<input type="button" value="Show Error on Tab2" id="add" />
<input type="button" value="Hide Error on Tab2" id="remove" />
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();

    $("#add").click(function(){
    $("#tab1").css('visibility',  'visible');
    });    

    $("#remove").click(function(){
    $("#tab1").css('visibility',  'hidden');
    });

});
```

**Css**

```
.boing {
    margin-left:5px;
    color:red;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sharing an idea from my previous work in your case you might try to use wizard forms. Check this out [Jquery Smart Wizard](http://mstratman.github.io/jQuery-Smart-Wizard/)

Comment: jquery smart wizard looks really nice, but I have already used jquery tabs and have used it throughout the project and cannot use this as of now. Thanks for the share !

Answer (score 0):

You can add a validation inside the properties of the elements e.g. `required="required"` to check for empty fields. This will restrict the user from navigating to the next tab if there is an error on a current given tab.